# Patterns in AreaSeries in TChart

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, teechart

i have TChart with TAreaSeries. I'd like to change Pattern in this Serie to Back Diagonal (AreaBrush = bsBDiagonal) but not for whole Serie, I need to change it only for some Values. Is it possible? I use Delphi7, TeeChart8.

Answer (score 1):

You could find an event that is fired each time a value is drawn. Then, you could play with it to change the series settings (or the chart canvas settings depending on the event) assigning a different brush or color depending on the `ValueIndex`.

In your case, this could be done using the series' `OnGetPointerStyle` event as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries) as TAreaSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues(10);
    Pointer.Visible:=true;
    OnGetPointerStyle:=Series1GetPointerStyle;
  end;
end;


function TForm1.Series1GetPointerStyle(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer): TSeriesPointerStyle;
begin
  if ValueIndex=3 then
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsBDiagonal
  else
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsSolid;

  result:=psNothing;
end;
```

Note in this case where I've changed the series brush for `ValueIndex=3` in `OnGetPointerstyle` event, the changes are visible in the area segment 4-5. This is because the `OnGetPointerstyle` event is actually called just after drawing the current area segment so the Brush style we've set will be applied the next time a value will be drawn.

---

EDIT:

As @Michael noticed in the comments, the only problem with this solution is how to change the pattern for the first segment. If the event above allows you to change the pattern of the segment from ValueIndex+1 to ValueIndex+2 and the first time it's called with ValueIndex=0, it doesn't seem to be possible to change the pattern for the segment from 0 to 1.

Note `OnGetPointerstyle` event is fired for all the points in the linked series each time the series is drawn. The first segment is drawn using the series pattern, so you just need to make sure the series pattern has the value you want to set to the first segment before starting to draw the series. You have two ways to do this:

1) You can set the pattern you want to show at the segment 0 to 1 when the last time `OnGetPointerstyle` event is fired (ValueIndex=Sender.Count-1). At this moment, all the segments have already been drawn and this will only be applied the next time the series will be drawn:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries) as TAreaSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues(10);
    Pointer.Visible:=true;
    AreaBrush:=bsBDiagonal;
    OnGetPointerStyle:=Series1GetPointerStyle;
  end;
end;

function TForm1.Series1GetPointerStyle(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer): TSeriesPointerStyle;
begin
  if (ValueIndex=0) or (ValueIndex=Sender.count-1) then
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsBDiagonal
  else
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsSolid;

  result:=psNothing;
end;
```

2) You could use `OnBeforeDrawSeries` event to set the pattern for the first segment:

```
uses Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=false;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TAreaSeries) as TAreaSeries do
  begin
    FillSampleValues(10);
    Pointer.Visible:=true;
    OnGetPointerStyle:=Series1GetPointerStyle;
  end;

  Chart1.OnBeforeDrawSeries:=BeforeDrawSeries;
end;

function TForm1.Series1GetPointerStyle(Sender: TChartSeries;
  ValueIndex: Integer): TSeriesPointerStyle;
begin
  if ValueIndex=0 then
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsBDiagonal
  else
    (Sender as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsSolid;

  result:=psNothing;
end;

procedure TForm1.BeforeDrawSeries(Sender: TObject);
begin
  (Chart1[0] as TAreaSeries).AreaBrush:=bsBDiagonal;
end;
```